# Rails 3.2 app seems to be caching queries across requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a Rails 3.2 app that is serving stale content.  A typical scenario:

1. an admin adds some new records in the back-end
2. user goes to view the index page for those resources
3. they don't show up on the page
4. they refresh; the resources are now there
5. they refresh; the resources are not there
6. etc.

I created a model/controller/view so I could test this out:

```
# app/models/cache_query_test.rb

class CacheQueryTest < ActiveRecord::Base
end

# app/controllers/cache_query_tests_controller.rb

class CacheQueryTestsController < ApplicationController
  def count
    @count = CacheQueryTest.count
    @mysql_time = CacheQueryTest.find_by_sql("SELECT NOW() AS mysql_time")

    respond_to do |wants|
      wants.text { render :layout => false }
    end
  end
end

# app/views/cache_query_tests/count.text.erb

==============
Rails MySQL Time: <%= @mysql_time.first.mysql_time %>
Ruby Time:        <%= Time.now.strftime "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" %>
Rails MySQL Count: <%= @count %>
```

I also have a small shell script running that periodically adds records to the cache_query_tests table in  the app's MySQL database so that, in theory, the database isn't caching queries.

When I hit the URL that displays my test page, I get a mixed bag of results, like:

```
==============
Rails MySQL Time: Mon Sep 16 10:40:57 UTC 2013
Ruby Time:        2013-09-16 10:40:58
Rails MySQL Count: 177
```

or:

```
==============
Rails MySQL Time: Mon Sep 16 09:47:46 UTC 2013
Ruby Time:        2013-09-16 10:16:32
Rails MySQL Count: 165
```

or:

```
==============
Rails MySQL Time: Mon Sep 16 09:50:02 UTC 2013
Ruby Time:        2013-09-16 10:41:32
Rails MySQL Count: 167
```

and so on...

In all cases, the "Ruby Time" is current and correct, so the page itself isn't getting cached.  However, as you can see, the "Rails MySQL Time" is often out of sync with Ruby Time.  As well, the "Rails MySQL Count" is quite often wrong too, despite the fact that I am adding records to the database, so this is why I think that something within the Rails stack is performing query caching.

To the best of my knowledge, Rails is only supposed to do [query caching within a request](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#sql-caching).  Here, something (maybe MySQL?  maybe Rack?  maybe Rails?) is doing it across requests.  Frankly, I'm pretty stumped about where to go from here.  While I would love a solution :), I'd also like some more opinions on where the problem could lie.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to help any unlucky SOB that ends up here with the same problem, we eventually traced this to the Octopus gem (https://github.com/tchandy/octopus).  Note that I'm not sure if this behaviour is intended or configurable, so I don't want to blame Octopus, but rather just note that this was the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Though it's difficult to tell for certain (as this relies on your MySQL configuration, not your Rails configuration) the most likely answer here is that your MySQL server is using [query cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-cache.html). From the documentation:

> The query cache stores the text of a SELECT statement together with
>   the corresponding result that was sent to the client. If an identical
>   statement is received later, the server retrieves the results from the
>   query cache rather than parsing and executing the statement again. The
>   query cache is shared among sessions, so a result set generated by one
>   client can be sent in response to the same query issued by another
>   client.

You can verify whether or not this is occurring on the database layer by using the [query cache select options](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-cache-in-select.html). Try changing your SQL statement to something like this:

`@mysql_time = CacheQueryTest.find_by_sql("SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE NOW() AS mysql_time")`

I bet afterwards you'll find that the time changes every time you retrieve it.

Comment: According to the [MySQL caching documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-cache-operation.html), MySQL isn't supposed to cache queries with NOW() in them, and is supposed to clear the cache when records are INSERTed (like I am doing).  Still, I'll give it a shot.  Thanks.